# Where is this AWS server placed

Tags: amazon-web-services

I cannot find the server with IP 54.240.3.17 in the IP ranges list published by Amazon https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json

According to ip-location it is in Seattle, but it should be in EU West.I know that the ip-location is normally not that reliable, but does anyone know why it is not in the IP ranges list?

Answer (score 0):

As the list of public AWS IP-ranges is pretty long and matching an IP-address with a network can be error prone I wrote a little script to check if the IP-address is really not included in the list:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ipaddress
import json
import urllib.request

IP_ADDRESS_TO_CHECK = ipaddress.IPv4Address('54.240.3.17')

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json')
json_response = json.loads(response.read())
for ip in json_response['prefixes']:
    if IP_ADDRESS_TO_CHECK in ipaddress.IPv4Network(ip['ip_prefix']):
        print(ip)
```

Running this does indeed verify that the IP address is currently not included in the list of public IPv4 ranges published by AWS.

I can only guess why that's the case, but it seems likely that AWS just hasn't updated the list yet to include the network the IP-address is part of. Note that the currently served list is already three days old, as you can see from the embedded `createDate`:

```
"createDate": "2019-10-18-19-53-09",
```